# python import the same file name programatically from different folders

Tags: python

I have the following structure

```
sites 
  - SiteA
    - Settings.py
  - SiteA
    - Settings.py
  - SiteA
    - Settings.py
```

all the settings.py file has a variable

DOMAIN_KEY = ''

Is there a way to programmically import this structure and look through this variable in all the setting files and print it?

**EDIT (Updated code):**

```
with cd(os.path.join(APPLICATION_DIR, 'config', 'sites')):
    output = run ("ls -l | grep \"^d\"|awk {'print $8'}") # run will execute and return list of folders
    for file in output.split():
        __module = __import__('%s' % file)
        print __module
        print __module.TIME_ZONE
        print __module.SITE_ID
```

The import is not working properly, am not sure how I can import the setting files without knowing the folder name.

Comment: Is "SiteA" a directory name? Should they have different names really? What's the location of the script you're running?

Comment: siteA is a python directory with __init__.py file. The script will run from the main directory (sites).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you do not have duplicate file names you can access these modules and its variables like this:

```
import SiteA.Settings as A, SiteB.Settings as B, SiteC.Settings as C
print(A.DOMAIN_KEY, B.DOMAIN_KEY, C.DOMAIN_KEY)
```

**EDIT:** Another option would be the `__import__()` statement, that lets you load a module with its name:

```
for char in "ABC":
    mod = __import__("Site%c.Settings")
    print(mod.DOMAIN_KEY)
```

**EDIT2:** according to the edit in the OP.

Why don't you just append the "Settings" module name after the folder you got from the script?

```
for file in output.split():
    __module = __import__('%s.Settings' % file)
    print __module.Settings.DOMAIN_KEY
```

Comment: If the former, he would also have to add an \_\_init\_\_.py in each of the directories to make sure they are recognized as packages.

Comment: You'd want to do `mod = __import__("Site%c.Settings" % char, fromlist=["Site%c" % char])`, or use `mod.Settings.DOMAIN_KEY` instead of `mod.DOMAIN_KEY`.

Comment: this wouldn't work for me because I don't know the folder names. I updated the post with the code am trying to use